# Loading different Views in Java depending on variables from a database?

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, netbeans

I'm more used to procedural programming and what I've done basically works but when I look at it I think it can't be very efficient and there must be a much better way of doing the same thing.  Could someone show me what it is? At the root of this is how to load different views from `main.java` and dispose of them based on the contents of a database.

I am building a database application with a Java Interface, using JDBC. I want to be able to load 3 different GUIs for 3 different users, depending on which one logs on.  My initial stab at this is to build a java bean class for each table in the database and corresponding Manager classes to deal with interacting with the database. At the user end of things, I load a login window for them to attempt to access the database. When the user enters their correct login details, these are saved to a Singleton class named `Session.java` for reference while they're using the program, so that I don't have to go back and forth to the database to check for their information. The Singleton class is then used to determine the appropriate interface to load for them. I was doing this from Main.java like this:

```
LoginScreen login = new LoginScreen();  
JohnsView john = new JohnsView();
MarysView mary = new MarysView();
PaulsView paul = new PaulsView();
login.setVisible(true);
login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//while the user has not completed login hide their database interface screen
while (!Session.isLoginSucessful()) {
   john.setVisible(false);
   mary.setVisible(false);
   paul.setVisible(false);
}
```

when the user enters their login details via the GUI I check if their user name and password matches an entry in the database. If it does I set the variables in the Singleton class named `Session.java` like 
this:

```
    Session.setTheUserID(user.getIduser());
    Session.setTheUserName(user.getUserName());
    Session.setTheUserPassword(user.getPassword());
    Session.setTheUserLevel(user.getUserLevel());
    Session.setTheUserStaffID(user.getStaffID());
     Session.setLoginSucessful(true);
```

then back in `main.java` I use a switch statement to `.dispose()` of the unneeded views and make the appropriate one visible like this:

```
    //dispose of login once it's finished with    
    login.dispose();

    //get the user 'level (1,2 or 3) from the singleton class...
    int usrLev = Session.getTheUserLevel();

    //check their level with the switch statement for the appropriate view to load
    switch(usrLev) {
        case 1:
            john.setVisible(true);
            mary.dispose();
            peter.dispose();
            break;
        case 2:
            mary.setVisible(true);
            john.dispose();
            peter.dispose();
            break;
        case 3:
            peter.setVisible(true);
            mary.dispose();
            peter.dispose();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I know I could approach this problem differently and put the login box into a bigger Jframe and manipulate the contents of the Jframe based on who logs on. I've looked at some examples of this in answer to other questions on here, but this wouldn't achieve what I want it to. I want to be able to load different views from Main depending on variables derived from the database. Do I need some kind of view manager class that's called from main? I've tried this a few times but end up deleting it because it doesn't make sense when I try it. I can't seem to figure this out in java.  Any help with understanding this and answering it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved this. Though rather than delete the post, I thought I'd leave it here for anyone else who is more used to procedural programming than OOP.

Basically nothing happens in Main apart from launching the first window of the application. In my case a login screen. Many people delete main, but I found it useful to keep it as I may want to do some multi-threading to handle communications with the database in the future, if I push the database onto a server rather than have it on my local machine.

Basically the code in the 3rd block above goes in the GUI code, inside the button action method that handles button presses for logging on. In that method you listen for input from the user, check if it matches what's in your database. If It doesn't tell them so through some visual feedback. If it does allow the code to progress to block three above, whereupon you load the view you want and call `this.dispose()` on the current view.

I'll leave this for a bit. if its not a useful contribution, I'll delete it.